# How is the transfer function of a state space representation computed in practice?

Tags: transfer-function, state-space, numerical-algorithms

I know that if you have a linear time invariant system defined by
$$ \dot{X} = AX+BU $$  $$Y = CX$$ by "Laplacing" the previous equations, you get the following transfer function in the Laplace domain :

$$Y(s) = C(A-sI)^{-1}BU(s) = H(s)U(s)$$  Let us focus on : $$H(s) = C(A-sI)^{-1}B$$

Indeed, many libraries allow to pass from the state space model to a transfer function model as for instance, the scipy [ss2tf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.ss2tf.html) function.

However, it is not straightforward to compute the coefficients or the poles/zeros of this transfer function. As is, evaluating the transfer function $H(s)$ in s requires to compute $(A-sI)^{-1}$ for each s, which is ridiculous. So I imagine there are better techniques used to compute the polynomials roots or coefficients.

Here are two Ideas that first came into my mind :

**First technique**

I guess using [minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) into the cofactor formula should work since it should not be too difficult to express every minor as a polynomial of s and compute their coefficients. Here is the cofactor formula :

$$(sI-A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(sI-A)}C^T$$ with $C^T$ the matrix of the cofactors of $sI-A$.

However, although I never checked for complexity, I heard that the inverse formula with minors is theoretically nice but is a very poor choice in practice to invert matrix (much heavier than Gauss for instance). At least this formula has the merit to show you that the poles of your transfer function will be the zeros of the characteristic polynomials of $A$ :
$$ det(sI-A)$$
I also have concerns about the numerical soundness of such a technique since it might very much depend on the conditioning number of $A$ : it is not a converging algorithm.

**Second technique**

If your matrix A represents a physical phenomenon, chances are that in absence of input your system variables will decrease to zero or some other constant. In that context it is not too crazy to imagine that we could show that $A^{n}  \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$.

We can use that :
$$A-sI = -s(I-\frac{1}{s}A)$$

and then if you have $(\frac{1}{s}A)^{n}  \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$ for $s$ above a certain threshold:
$$(I-\frac{1}{s}A)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{s}A)^{k} \approx \sum_{k=0}^{N}(\frac{1}{s}A)^{k}$$

I guess if we say that $A$ is $p \times p$ you could truncate when your first $p$ polynomial coefficients have converged. But then you might compute way too much, and some coefficients might get obnoxiously small and irrelevant.

Comment: I'd look at the ss2tf code -- it's got to be buried in there.  Possibly after some digging into whatever underlying math package is actually doing it.  _A way_ you could do this is to decompose $A$ into it's Jordan form and a set of eigenvectors.  Then you can have the whole system in the form $\dot x' = J x' + B' u$, $y = C' x'$.  With the state evolution matrix in Jordan form, the Laplace domain transfer function polynomials should, if not fall at your feet, then at least be computable in a sensible way.

Comment: I believe the Jordan form to be a good idea. However you still end up to compute the inverse matrix in the end. I dug in the code and they seem to have gone for a cofactor-like approach : they compute the denominator of all the whole transfer function as $\chi_{A}$ but then the numerators are not exactly the cofactors :
`for k in range(nout):`
        `Ck = atleast_2d(C[k, :])`
        `num[k] = poly(A - dot(B, Ck)) + (D[k] - 1) * den`

Comment: This is weird weird since it seems heavier to me to compute poly(A - dot(B, Ck)) that a minor of $(sI-A)$

Comment: It's a StackExchange tradition that if you find the answer to your own question, you submit it.

Comment: "This is weird weird since..."  I can't think of any earthly reason that you'd have a high need for speed in translating state space models into transfer functions.  In such cases, even in production code, it's often better to lean toward readability and algorithmic clarity than to push hard on making it faster at the cost of making it opaque and perhaps fragile.

Comment: I actually haven't found the answer yet. I don't get why the numerators of the transfer function are $\chi_(A-BC_k)$ with $C_k$ being the k-th line of $C$. I looked a little bit but I couldn't find a simple algebra link between $C(A-Is)^{-1}B$ and $\chi_(A-BC_k)$ using the cofactor formula for $(A-Is)^{-1}$. It is my intuition that there is one but until I have found one I can't prove it. Posting it might be misleading future readers in case I'm wrong.